# Server Side Events & Historical Data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, real-time

I am using PHP and MySQL in order to display live data on my webpage, refreshing every 1 second. All is currently working as expected although I would like to implement one new feature.

Currently on `$( document ).ready()` I start the live data feed by retrieving and displaying single rows of data from a `transactions` table. I can also start/stop the feed. Good so far.

I would now like to display the live data **and** have it **start** from *the last 100 transactions*. So for example, when a user opens the webpage they will initially see the past 100 transactions, **then** the live feed will start immediately afterwards (101, 102, 103, etc..).

Currently when the page is loaded the live feed starts at whatever transaction is returned by the sql query. Whereas I need it to start at that point *minus 100*

The past 100 transactions could -100 from the `SerialNo` as this is a unique, auto increment key in the database.

Everything is working regarding the live feed, including start/stop buttons. So I feel the issue is due to my query, especially the `LIMIT 1` part. I have tried changing this to `LIMIT 100` but when I do the webpage shows 100 records every 1 second.

I have two files, `data.php` and `index.html`. I have included the code for both below.

**data.php**

```
session_start(); 
include 'conn.php'; // database connection
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$query = "SELECT TimeStamp, SerialNo FROM transactions ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //send request every x seconds
    echo "retry: 1000\n\n"; 
    echo "id: " .$row["SerialNo"]. "\n\n";

    if ($_SESSION["lastSerialNo"] != $row["SerialNo"]) {
    //store new "last" serial no in the session
        $_SESSION["lastSerialNo"] = $row["SerialNo"];
    //...send data to client
        echo "data: ".$row['SerialNo']. ' ' .$row['TimeStamp']. "\n\n";
        flush();
    }
    else {
    // do nothing
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("document").ready(function() {
        // set the default stopped flag to false
        var is_stopped = false;
        var source = new EventSource("data.php");
        var offline;

        source.onmessage = function(event) {

          if (is_stopped) {
            // get data sent from data.php
            offline = event.data;
            // Put into storage
            localStorage.setItem(event.lastEventId, offline);
            // Retrieve from storage
            offline = localStorage.getItem("offline");
          }

          if (!is_stopped) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "New transaction: " + event.data + "<br>";
          }
        };

        $("document").ready(function() {
          $("#start").click(function() {
            // set stopped flag to false
            is_stopped = false;
            // loop through the localstorage 
            for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "New transaction: " + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) + " *<br>";
            }
            // clear local storage
            localStorage.clear();
          });

          $("#stop").click(function() {
            // set the stopped flag to true
            is_stopped = true;
          });
        }); 
      }); //end dom ready
</script>

<div id="result"><!--Server response here--></div>
<button id="stop"> stop</button>
<button id="start"> start</button>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "start at the last 100 transactions"?

Comment: Not following entirely. The issue is server side, yes?

Comment: Still not following. Adjust query at `php`

Comment: Still not gathering what issue is?

Comment: it sounds like you want to gather the previous 100 transactions and then keep adding on any new transactions is this correct? 

so, in other words, you show the first 100 then you enter 5 more and are showing 105 on the page. can you confirm if that is the behavior you want?

Comment: @ttallierchio I'm not 'entering' transactions anywhere. The transactions are being retrieved automatically from a MySQL database. But yes, your logic is correct. I want to gather the previous 100 transactions and then keep adding on any new transactions.